# How to process each entity in SonataAdminBundle list view?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

How to apply some code to each entity being displayed in Admin's list view?

For example, if I have a `TagManager` and need to load tags for each entity being displayed, how do I do that? Is there a method to override in entity's Admin or can I bind to some list form event? I could not find a place to do that.

I don't wan't to bind to entity's `onLoad` event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** In your entityAdminController :

```
public function listAction()
{
    if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('LIST')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    $datagrid = $this->admin->getDatagrid();
    $formView = $datagrid->getForm()->createView();

    foreach($datagrid->getResults() as $object)
    {
        //do what you want with $object
    }

    // set the theme for the current Admin Form
    $this->get('twig')->getExtension('form')->renderer->setTheme($formView, $this->admin->getFilterTheme());

    return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate('list'), array(
        'action'   => 'list',
        'form'     => $formView,
        'datagrid' => $datagrid
    ));
}
```

Comment: Entity has no doctrine association with `Tag` entity (and there cannot be one, as the tags are global) therefore I have to manually set tags for the entity so that they are accessible from the template.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. Is there a way to add extra entry to $datagrid->getResults() which didn't come from the database?