# Sonata how to display all instaces of entity

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to display all instances of my Product entity in my PageAdmin formMapper. I searched for something like that in the doc but can't find it. Does anyone know how to do it?

here is my PageAdmin

```
<?php
namespace MyShop\ShopBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class PageAdmin extends Admin
{
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            // ->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'Post Title'))
            // ->add('author', 'entity', array('class' => 'MyShop\UserBundle\Entity\User'))
            ->add('title', 'text', array('label' => 'Page Title'))

        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('title')
        ;
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            // ->addIdentifier('title')
            ->add('title')
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'edit' => array(),
                    )
                ))
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the CRUDController for this entity, and particularly the listViewAction, as seen on ths thread : [How to process each entity in SonataAdminBundle list view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653033/how-to-process-each-entity-in-sonataadminbundle-list-view)

if you need more information on the CRUDController overriding, see this page : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/tutorial/creating_your_first_admin_class/defining_crud_controller.html